# SignIn Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm designing a stored procedure for a website signin and have

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Member where Email=@EMail and PW=@PW)    
BEGIN 
   Select MemberId . . .
END
ELSE    
BEGIN    
   UPDATE FailCount +1
```

How should I next check for FailCount >= FailLimit ?

Specifically I've searched the following:

1. `IF. . . THEN`
2. `CASE . .  WHEN`
3. `DECLARE` variables and `SELECT INTO` those variables which are then compared (rather than comparing two SELECTS from the same table).

All suggestions appreciated!

Comment: ***PLease*** tell us you're **NOT** storing the passwords in **plain text** in your database table!!!

Comment: Definitely not but thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT @Fail = FailCount 
FROM USER_TABLE
WHERE Email = @EMail;

IF @Fail >= @FailLimit THEN
BEGIN
     /*  PUT YOUR CODE HERE */
END

ELSE
BEGIN

    IF EXISTS (SELECT Member FROM USER_TABLE where Email=@EMail and PW=@PW)    
    BEGIN 
       Select MemberId . . .
    END

    ELSE    
    BEGIN    
       UPDATE USER_TABLE
       SET FailCount = FailCount + 1
       WHERE Email = @EMail;
    END
END
```